# Looking for a Strategy to get multiple tables from a MySQL Query in PHP

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I'm trying to build a set of results from a query in a PHP page.  My where clause is complicated and potentially expensive.  In my usual languages I'd do something like:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ShortList (ID INT);
INSERT INTO ShortList
  SELECT ID FROM Table1 WHERE {Super long query};

SELECT * FROM Table1 JOIN ShortList ON ShortList.ID = Table1.ID;
SELECT * FROM Table2 JOIN ShortList ON ShortList.ID = Table2.Table1ID;
SELECT * FROM Table3 JOIN ShortList ON ShortList.ID = Table3.Table1ID;
SELECT * FROM Table4 JOIN ShortList ON ShortList.ID = Table4.Table1ID;
```

Then I'd iterate through each resultset pulling each row.  Given this data it's not very easy to join across all of the tables; this would result in a lot of duplicate data.

So what's the PHP way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured this out.  I'm used to a transaction model where I have to explicitly put multiple statements into a single transaction.  PHP/MySQL assumes that multiple queries are in the same transaction.  So ultimately the way to do this is to run one query per SQL statement:

```
mysql_query("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ShortList (ID INT)");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO ShortList SELECT ID FROM Table1 WHERE {Super long query}");

mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Table1 JOIN ShortList ON ShortList.ID = Table1.ID");
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Table2 JOIN ShortList ON ShortList.ID = Table2.Table1ID");
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Table3 JOIN ShortList ON ShortList.ID = Table3.Table1ID");
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Table4 JOIN ShortList ON ShortList.ID = Table4.Table1ID");
```

Hope that helps anyone else with the same problem.

Comment: that's true, but since the number of rows in the main query is so large, it would have helped people answering your question had you said so.

Comment: Good point, I'll try to make my questions clearer in the future.  

It's not so much that I know the numbers will be that large (they'll probably average around 100), but I like to protect against those kinds of runaway conditions

Comment: MySQL defaults to autocommit, so those four selects aren't actually in a transaction unless you explicitly either SET autocommit=0; or you execute "BEGIN" or "START TRANSACTION".

Answer (score 0):

I haven't ever done anything quite as complex as this, but I suggest you create a database access class to handle your queries. Then you can create multiple objects of that class to hold the three result sets simultaneously. Something like...

```
$big_query   = new database_access ();
$table1      = new database_access ();
$other_table = new database_access ();

$big_query->query ("large query string");

while ($row_array = $big_query->fetch ())
{
    $table1->query ("table 1 query string accessing ".$row_array[id]);

    while ($table1_row_array = $table1->fetch ())
    {
        $other_table->query ("other table query accessing ".$table1_row_array[table1ID]);

        while ($other_table_row_array = $other_table->fetch ())
        {
            // deal with results
        }

        // ...etc...

    }

}
```

I hope that's what you had in mind and I haven't gone off and answered a different question.

Comment: I've thought about that approach, but it requires several round trips to the database.  If your large query string returns 100,000 rows, and I've got 4 tables to query, I'll be running 400,000 independent queries on the database.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to try writing an SQL Procedure (Stored Procedure) to accomplish this. Procedures are meant to handle complex/multiple queries.

What RDBMS are you using ? Most modern RDBMS support stored procedures.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure

Just in case, if you are using MySQL -> http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-storedproc.html

Comment: OK, but that doesn't address how to get multiple resultsets out.  So I move all of this into a stored procedure.  I still don't want to run the predicate more than once.